# Is there a shorter way to filter a DataObject?

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

I filter `myData`  object with two lines but is there a shorter way of doing this?

I want to have a new object. **name** with id **26** must be removed from the **names** array.

It's ok to use ES2018 features.

Is there any way to make the modification process shorter?

```js
const myData = {
  names: [{
      id: "1",
      name: "Streptocjhgjsis "
    },
    {
      id: "26",
      name: "aksdfja"
    },
    {
      id: "22",
      name: "kasjdfakj iakd"
    }
  ]
};
let filteredData = myData.names.filter((item) => item.id !== "26");
let newDataObject = {
  names: filteredData
};
console.log(newDataObject);
```

### Is there a way to make this shorter?

Comment: To filter an array then inject it into an object is working but ... It's just ugly.

Comment: How about `let newDataObject = { names: myData.names.filter((item) => item.id !== "26") }`

Comment: You could use argument destruction to avoid declaring argument name `filter(({ id }) => id !== '26')` but other than that "Do not fix what is not broken" :)

Comment: Why do you think it's ugly? It's perfectly readable code. You could use a [shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) by using `let names = myData.names.filter(...)` and then `let newObject = { names }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get result to another object first and directly set it to your desired object like `names: myData.names.filter((item) => item.id !== "26")`.

Test it below.

```js
const myData = {
  names: [{
      id: "1",
      name: "Streptocjhgjsis "
    },
    {
      id: "26",
      name: "aksdfja"
    },
    {
      id: "22",
      name: "kasjdfakj iakd"
    }
  ]
};

let newDataObject = {
  names: myData.names.filter((item) => item.id !== "26")
};
console.log(newDataObject);
```